# Let $\pi:X\to Y$ and $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous, is there $g:Y\to \mathbb{R}$ with $f=g\circ \pi$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X$, $Y$ be topological spaces and $\pi:X\to Y$ be a surjective continuous map. It is clear that if $g:Y\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function, then $f=g\circ \pi:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function.

Let $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function, Is there a continuous function $g:Y\to \mathbb{R}$  such that $f=g\circ \pi$?

It seems that there is no such function in general, but I do not know any proof for it.

Is there conditions on $\pi:X\to Y$ to imply that for every continuous function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ there is a continuous function $g:Y\to \mathbb{R}$  such that $f=g\circ \pi$?

Comment: Interesting. Looks like you have run into the **lifting** problem. Have you seen some Algebraic Topology before?

Comment: There is one trivial necessary condition: $f$ has to be constant on the fibers of $\pi$.

Comment: @epsilon-emperor, Thanks. I have not studied Algebraic Topology, Can you please give a  reference for it?

Comment: If $\pi(x_1)=\pi(x_2)$ and $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$ then there is no such $g.$ I guess that is the same as Mindlack’s comment, but for a general audience.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, In the other cases, can we say that there is a such $g$?

Comment: Pretty trivially, if $Y$ is finite and the range of $f$ is infinite, there can be no such function. I suspect it's true in general for if the cardinality of $Y$ is less than the range of $f$

Comment: You need: Given any open set $U$ in $\mathbb R$ that $\pi(f^{-1}(U))$ is open in $\pi(X).$ If $\pi$ is an open map, you will satisfy this condition, but the condition is weaker than $\pi$ being an open map. Don’t know if this condition is sufficient.

Answer (score 6):

A simple counterexample is when $\pi$ is constant (and so $Y=\{*\}$ is a singleton) while $f$ is not. Because if $\pi$ is constant then the composition of $\pi$ with any function is constant as well.

As for conditions you may want to read about various [lifting properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting_property) or maybe [projective objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_object#Examples) in topological spaces. Note that such properties are rather rare in general.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment, if there are $x,x’ \in X$ such that $f(x)\neq f(x’)$ and $\pi(x)=\pi(x’)$, then such a $g$ cannot exist. The other answer is an example of this situation.

Conversely, if $f$ is constant on the fibers of $\pi$ (ie if $\pi(x)=\pi(x’)$ implies $f(x)=f(x’)$ for every $x,x’ \in X$), then such a function $g$ exists and is unique, at least set-theoretically. The question is then to find whether this $g$ is continuous. If $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ is an open subset, $g^{-1}(U)=\pi(\pi^{-1}g^{-1}(U))=\pi(f^{-1}(U))$.

Thus, $g$ is continuous iff for every open subset $U \subset \mathbb{R}$, $\pi(f^{-1}(U))$ is an open subset of $Y$. For instance, it is sufficient that $f$ be open (and the condition above must hold too).